# How do i limit the calling of a function - Accept behaviourSubject.next only onetime for 2000ms in Angular with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Component that by clicking a Button calls a Method in a Service.

```
public wasClicked(){
    this.myService.writexy('1')
  }
```

The Service has a BehaviourSubject and the Method that was called, that logs some Output. I want that it logs only one time in 2000ms even if the Button was clicked several times.

```
sub = new BehaviorSubject(1);

writexy(x){
    this.sub.next(x)
    this.sub.pipe(
      throttle(val => interval(2000)),
      //debounce(val => interval(6000)),
      //debounceTime(2000),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(() =>  console.log('2'))
```

As you can see I have tried throttle, debounce and debounceTime, but it keeps printing  '2' as often as I click the Button. I have also tried to use a ReplaySubject with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: thx, could you give me an example, please. I don't understand how to get the debounce out and subscribe to the Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're recreating a new `Observable` every time `writexy` is called, so every new `Observable` will have its own, new `debounceTime` that has never run before. You need to move the `debounceTime` out so it's maintained across all calls. That might look something like this:

```
// Script

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  sub = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  debounced = this.sub.pipe(debounceTime(2000));

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debounced.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('2');
    });
  }

  writexy(x) {
    this.sub.next(x);
  }
}


// Template

<button (click)="writexy(9)">Button</button>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jm8uq2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is a example StackBlitz (I have no idea how long that link will live for).

Comment: Looks good, I have replaced the BehaviourSubject with a ReplaySubject, because the BehaviourSubject fired initially without clicking. I have put the debounce.subscribe into the constructor because it is a Service and has no ngOninit(). Or would you suggest something else? 

`sub = new ReplaySubject(1);
  debounced = this.sub.pipe(debounceTime(3000));`

`constructor() {
    this.debounced.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('2');
      this.doSomething()
    });
  }`

`writexy(x) {
    this.sub.next(x);
  }`